# How to install bash-it in Windows 10 bash system

Tags: windows-10, bash, shell, git, window

I work a lot with git and [bash-it](https://github.com/Bash-it/bash-it) is a great visualization tool especially when working with branches. I was hoping someone knows how to install "bash-it" (or any similar program) within the Windows 10 bash environment?

I've Googled about it but most articles are about setting it up on a Mac.

I was hoping to get it installed so that working with git branches becomes easier.

#### Benefits of having bash-it

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: What happened when you followed the install instructions?

Comment: @DavidPostill Well after I run the commands mentioned there, nothing gets changed. My bash experience remains the same. Then I saw this article: http://mandymadethis.com/pimp-your-command-line/ for mac and realized, may be there is something more needed to be done. So, I asked here, in hope may be someone can write up a nice step-by-step process which will help everyone.

Comment: Are there any status or error messages when running the install instructions?

Comment: @8bittree Not that I saw

Comment: @iSaumya See my answer below: is it possible that you answered `y` when it asked if you'd like to keep your .bashrc? If so, try again allowing it to move your .bashrc aside and see if that changes anything. Also, check you're running as Administrator.

Comment: You need to customise it after you have installed it ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's unclear to me whether you're running into problems, or if you just needed a walkthrough?

I'm assuming you already have Bash on Windows set up to the point where you can open a Bash window. Once you've done so, make you sure you run it (found at C:\Windows\System32\bash.exe) with Administrator privileges (right-click bash in File Explorer and choose **Run as administrator**; you can also create a shortcut which you can then pin to your taskbar that will run bash as Administrator every time).

Once that's done, all you have to know is that when you try to run a program that isn't installed, bash will reply like this:

```
~/src$ attr
The program 'attr' is currently not installed. You can install it by typing:
sudo apt-get install attr
```

Just do that (e.g., `sudo apt-get install $whatever`) whenever you need a program that isn't installed.

Following [the instructions](https://github.com/Bash-it/bash-it#install) on the Bash-it GitHub page worked for me using Bash in this way:

```
~/src $ git clone https://github.com/Bash-it/bash-it.git
Cloning into 'bash-it'...
remote: Counting objects: 6339, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (27/27), done.
remote: Total 6339 (delta 15), reused 6 (delta 6), pack-reused 6304
Receiving objects: 100% (6339/6339), 34.99 MiB | 13.00 MiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (2867/2867), done.
Checking connectivity... done.
~/src $ cd bash-it/
trey@MYHOST:~/src/bash-it$ ./install.sh
Installing bash-it
Would you like to keep your .bashrc and append bash-it templates at the end? [y/N]
Your original .bashrc has been backed up to .bashrc.bak
Copied the template .bashrc into ~/.bashrc, edit this file to customize bash-it

Enabling sane defaults

Installation finished successfully! Enjoy bash-it!
To start using it, open a new tab or 'source /home/trey/.bashrc'.

To show the available aliases/completions/plugins, type one of the following:
  bash-it show aliases
  bash-it show completions
  bash-it show plugins

To avoid issues and to keep your shell lean, please enable only features you really want to use.
Enabling everything can lead to issues.
trey@MYHOST:~/src/bash-it$ source ~/.bashrc

 2016-09-28 13:05:47 ☆  MYHOST in ~/src/bash-it
± |master ✓| → bash-it show aliases
Alias               Enabled?  Description
ag                    [ ]     the silver searcher (ag) aliases
ansible               [ ]     ansible abbreviations
apt                   [ ]     Apt and dpkg aliases for Ubuntu and Debian distros.
atom                  [ ]     Atom.io editor abbreviations
bundler               [ ]     ruby bundler
clipboard             [ ]     pbcopy and pbpaste shortcuts to linux
curl                  [ ]     Curl aliases for convenience.
docker-compose        [ ]     docker-compose abbreviations
docker                [ ]     docker abbreviations
emacs                 [ ]     emacs editor
fuck                  [ ]
general               [x]     general aliases
git                   [ ]     common git abbreviations
gitsvn                [ ]     common git-svn abbreviations
heroku                [ ]     heroku task abbreviations
hg                    [ ]     mercurial abbreviations
homebrew-cask         [ ]     homebrew-cask abbreviations
homebrew              [ ]     homebrew abbreviations
jitsu                 [ ]     jitsu task abbreviations
laravel               [ ]     laravel artisan abbreviations
maven                 [ ]     maven abbreviations
npm                   [ ]     common npm abbreviations
osx                   [ ]     osx-specific aliases
phoenix               [ ]     phoenix abbreviations
rails                 [ ]     rails abbreviations
svn                   [ ]     common svn abbreviations
textmate              [ ]     textmate abbreviations
tmux                  [ ]     Tmux terminal multiplexer
todo                  [ ]     todo.txt-cli abbreviations
vagrant               [ ]     vagrant aliases
vim                   [ ]     vim abbreviations

to enable an alias, do:
$ bash-it enable alias  <alias name> [alias name]... -or- $ bash-it enable alias all

to disable an alias, do:
$ bash-it disable alias <alias name> [alias name]... -or- $ bash-it disable alias all

 2016-09-28 13:05:57 ☆  MYHOST in ~/src/bash-it
± |master ✓| → ~
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. I've successfully installed it.